# How to stop a method being called when accesing its attributes like return values

Tags: python, class

The question is the following: How to stop a method being called when its attributes are, in fact, return values, that are necessary in another method, of another class.

This is how the program was written:

```
class S1():

      def __init__(self):
         pass

      def m2(self):
         #some values

      def m3(self):
         S2.m6()
         S1.m5()
         S2.m7()

      def m4(self):
           #some values

      def m5(self):

           n = int(input('Enter the number of games to simulate: '))

           prob = int(input('Enter the prob. for the player to win first game: '))

           #some values to calculate the probability

           return p, n


class S2(S1):

       def __init__(self):
            pass

       def m6(self):
            print('This program simulates a game')

       def m7(self):     

            print('Games simulated: ', S1().m5()[1])
            print('Points for 1st player: ', S1().m5()[0])



var1 = S1()
var1.m3()
```

Calling `var1.m3()` returns this result, which is repeating the function calls, because of the `p` and `n`attributes that are retrieved in the method `m7()` through this syntax:

```
 print('Games simulated: ', S1().m5()[1])       #the value of n variable
 print('Points for the player: ', S1().m5()[0])   #the value of p variable
```

It results in this effect:

```
This program simulates a game

Enter the number of games to simulate:  10

Enter the prob for the player to win first game:  0.5

Enter the number of games to simulate:  10

Enter the prob for the player to win first game:  0.5

Games simulated: 10

Enter the number of games to simulate:   10

Enter the prob for the player to win first game:   0.5

Points for the player: 6
```

Basically, `S1().m5()[1]` and `S1().m5()[0]` calls the functions, but I wanted to retrieve the  values `p` and `n` from the tuple returned by `m5()`.

The methods are interspersed and I am having some difficulty understanding why is this happening and how to avoid this type of repetions when using class attributes.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it like this:

```
class S1():

      def __init__(self):
         pass

      def m2(self):
         #some values

      def m3(self):
         S2.m6()
         p, n = S1.m5()
         S2.m7(p, n)

      def m4(self):
           #some values

      def m5(self):

           n = int(input('Enter the number of games to simulate: '))

           prob = int(input('Enter the prob. for the player to win first game: '))

           #some values to calculate the probability

           return p, n


class S2(S1):

       def __init__(self):
            pass

       def m6(self):
            print('This program simulates a game')

       def m7(self, p, n):     

            print('Games simulated: ', n)
            print('Points for 1st player: ', p)



var1 = S1()
var1.m3()
```

I hope I didn't mix up `p` and `n`, but the general gist should come accross..

Comment: Thanks!! This  is much more simplified. I appreciate your help. Thanks again!!

Comment: No problem, ask away if anything is unclear. I'm by no means an expert in python, but maybe I can help :)

Comment: I will ask again, definitely. There are many things that  I still have uncertainties about.

Comment: The Zen of Python is something indispensable  when writing code, although some types of syntaxes seem challenging. Wonderful! Your help was enlightening! I need to read many times the Zen of Python!